# Error in installing Superset on GKE using Helm v2.17

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, apache-superset

I need to install Superset on GKE. I am following this guide https://howchoo.com/kubernetes/how-to-install-apache-superset-on-a-gke-kubernetes-cluster to do the same. It is suggested here to use Helm to install Superset. I have installed Helm v2.17.
I have installed and initialized Helm using the following statements:

```
$ curl https://baltocdn.com/helm/signing.asc | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https --yes
$ echo "deb https://baltocdn.com/helm/stable/debian/ all main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/helm-stable-debian.list
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install helm2
$ helm init
```

In the next step I want to install Superset.
Superset's official site says we need to run `helm upgrade --install superset ./install/helm/superset` to install Superset on a Kubernetes cluster.

On running the command I get the following as output:

```
 $ helm upgrade --install superset ./install/helm/superset
Release "superset" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: path "./install/helm/superset" not found
```

As you can see the path itself doesn't exist. I have inspected the directory and tried manually creating a directory named 'Superset' (with Helm's file - `get_helm.sh` - moved to this directory). Then installed Superset in it, but I get the following error:

```
 $ ls 
get_helm.sh  kubectl.exe  README-cloudshell.txt  superset-config.py
 $ mkdir Superset     
 $ ls 
get_helm.sh  kubectl.exe  README-cloudshell.txt  Superset  superset-config.py
 $ mv get_helm.sh Superset
 $ cd Superset
 $ ls
get_helm.sh 
 $ helm upgrade --install superset Superset
Error: no Chart.yaml exists in directory "/home/<username>/Superset"
```

I am not able to figure out where Helm is installed. It is supposed to exist in `./install/helm` so that Superset can be installed in this path.
How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install `superset` using:

```sh
helm install cloudposse-incubator/superset
```

Installing the chart:

```
helm repo rm cloudposse-incubator 2>/dev/null
helm repo add cloudposse-incubator https://charts.cloudposse.com/incubator/
helm install --name my-release stable/superset
```

Reference document:

- https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/cloudposse/superset

---

About error:

You are getting error due to not running command from the inside of helm directory.

**GitHub source**:

- https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/superset

You can clone whole Github repo locally:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/helm/charts.git
```

Go inside **helm** directory.

Go to **stable/superset** directory:

```sh
cd stable/superset
```

Here you can also run a command like `helm install stable/superset`

or outside of the directory, you can run:

```sh
helm install superset ./stable/superset
```

**Alternatively**, you can also download helm chart locally using

```sh
helm fetch stable/superset --untar
```

After this go to the directory and run the same command.